# Render Iusse ,Using Async startAsync() in Grails 2.0.1

Tags: grails, asynchronous, render

using servlet 3.0 async method when we render a string it's ok,but we can not render a page.

```
def index() {
    def ctx = startAsync()
    ctx.start {
        do something.........
        ctx.complete()
    }
    render "hello" 
}
```

### it's ok

but

```
def index() {
    def ctx = startAsync()
        ctx.start {
        do something.........
        ctx.complete()
    }
    render(view:xxx.page) 
}
```

it not work ok

Comment: I am sorry, I will not be able to help you here. 
But I do not understand what this "startAsync" method does. 
What do we mean by asynchronous actions ? 

If I call for example your index async function from a page, what will be different from a standard action call ?

Answer (score 0):

After beating my head against the wall on this same question, I finally figured out the solution. The code you want is:

```
def index() {
    def ctx = startAsync()
        ctx.start {
        do something.........
        ctx.dispatch()
    }
    render(view:xxx.page) 
}
```

So, here's how I think it works. Every call to ctx.start() creates a new response. If you close the AsyncContext with ctx.complete(), the child async responses are somehow merged and replace the original response, or merge with it. If you close the AsyncContext with ctx.dispatch(), the child async responses are discarded and the original response is used.

The reason, I think, that it was working for you with a String and not more advanced rendering behavior is that layout / view rendering in Grails uses a special SiteMesh response object. When ctx.complete() was run, the new response was of a different class, so it wouldn't do the advanced rendering.

Answer (score 0):

you want to call `ctx.dispatch()` to dispatch the view rendering layer rather than `ctx.complete()` which finishes the request..
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#asynchronousRequestProcessing

You want something like this:

```
def index() {
    def ctx = startAsync()
        ctx.start {
        do something.........
        render(view:xxx.page, model: [foo:"bar"])
        ctx.dispatch()
    } 
}
```